# GroupBy function to order by boolean

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

**edit**

I'm a fool and had a typo in my controller, it's all good now. (it's been a very long week)

---

Ok, this is something i'm not sure of. I'm thinking about implementing what i want in a different way but I want to find out if there's a way to do this.

I have an `IQueryable` object and in my table, i have a column of type `bool` and wish to order it by true/false in a table.

Here's something along the lines of what I've tried:

```
mQueryableObject.OrderBy(model => model.myBoolean);
```

this doesn't give me the expected result, as I would half expect.

So is there any way to order an `IQueryable` object (LINQ) by boolean value (true/false).

I'd really appreciate some insight.

Comment: You want the true values first then the false values?

Comment: What would be your expected result and what are you getting that's wrong?

Comment: @ShaiCohen Well for order, it has an OrderByDescending which i use for the other ones, so it ultimately doesn't matter which order they come in because i can alter it either way.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I want the true and false values separated, I'm getting them in a random order that im not sure where is coming from.

Comment: OK. What expected result do you want? Is the answer by @Jon Skeet the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this doesn't give me the expected result, as I would half expect.

Well without knowing what you expect, it's hard to know what's wrong here. It's also not clear whether you've really got that `OrderBy` call as a statement *by itself*. If so, that's the problem - LINQ operators don't mutate an existing query; they return a *new* query. For example, this *may* be all you need:

```
mQueryableObject = mQueryableObject.OrderBy(model => model.myBoolean);
```

This will sort `false` before `true`, by the way. If you want it the other way round, just use:

```
mQueryableObject = mQueryableObject.OrderBy(model => !model.myBoolean);
```

Comment: I'm expecting what you're describing, true before false and false before true, but i'm getting a random result. It must be somewhere else in the code then. I will update if i find the problem, any more info i should provide?

Comment: Accepting your answer as it informed me that I was querying properly, and helped me determine the problem was elsewhere